# LVM2: vgscan fails to recreate lvmtab

Tags: lvm

I recently moved an LVM array from one server to another. When I tried to recreate the lvmtab with pvscan/vgscan, it successfully found my 3 disks, but do not recreate lvm tab.

```
# pvscan -v
Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
Wiping internal VG cache
Walking through all physical volumes
PV /dev/sdb1   VG vg0   lvm2 [4.00 GiB / 0    free]
PV /dev/sdc1   VG vg0   lvm2 [4.00 GiB / 0    free]
PV /dev/sdd1   VG vg0   lvm2 [4.00 GiB / 0    free]
Total: 3 [11.99 GiB] / in use: 3 [11.99 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]


# vgscan -v
Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
Wiping internal VG cache
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Finding all volume groups
Finding volume group "vg0"
Found volume group "vg0" using metadata type lvm2


# lvscan -v
Finding all logical volumes
inactive          '/dev/vg0/opt' [11.99 GiB] inherit
```

At the end, I have no /dev/vg0 and no /etc/lvmtab.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have no lvmtab on my system and the man page for vgscan doesn't mention this file. Why do you think it is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lvchange -ay /dev/vg0/opt
```

The volume is not activeated, with this command you actually activate it.